# How to add github libraries to gradle workflow?

Tags: build, gradle, build-process

I'm new to build tools and gradle. I'm currently developing for android. I've found a library on Github I would like to use in my app.
What is the best way to create this dependency? The library doesn't have ant, maven or even gradle support.

Some options that came to my mind:
1) Fork the repo and add gradle support.
2) Clone the repo and add maven support then add it to the local maven repo.

What do the experts think how to handle such dependencies?

Comment: Is the library artifact available on GitHub with a specific version?

Comment: The project/library doesn't have artifacts.

Comment: I'd try to ask the library implementor to publish the artifact with a specific version or send in a pull request.

Comment: You can import the repository using https://JitPack.io service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the library only publish sources, not binaries, you don't have any other option rather than build it yourself. 
Once you did that, you can host the binary in binary repository (like Artifactory) for sharing it with your colleagues, or even publish it on a distribution platform (like Bintray) for anyone who want to use it. For the later, you'll be able to pass the ownership (and the maintenance burden) to the original author in any moment.